# Cross norms on tensor product of universal $C^*$-algebras and Kirchberg property

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

Let $G$ be a locally compact group and let $C^* (G)$ be the universal $C^*$-algebra of $G$; i.e., the completion of the convolution algebra $L^1(G)$ with respect to the norm $||f||=\sup_\pi||\pi(f)||$, where $\pi$ runs over all non-degenerate representations of $L^1(G)$ (seen as an involutive Banach algebra) in some $B(H)$.

> **Question:** Is it known any example of a **countable discrete non-amenable** group such that
>   $$
> C^* (G)\otimes_{\min}C^* (G)=C^* (G)\otimes_{\max}C^* (G)
> $$

Edit: the original question was for general locally compact groups but, as observed by Scott and Yemon, $SL(2,\mathbb C)$ already works as an example, as well as any connected group. In relation to Connes' problem (see below), I am more interested in countable (and discrete) groups.

For $G=\mathbb F_\infty$, the statement above is equivalent to Connes' embedding conjecture, by an unexpected and beautiful theorem of Eberhard Kirchberg (Inventiones Math. 1994). Somebody asked me the previous question during a talk and, to be honest, I have no idea.

After talking with some people, it seems that this problem is open in *both directions*

> **Question 2** Is it known any example of a **countable discrete** group such that
>   $$
> C^* (G)\otimes_{\min}C^* (G)\neq C^* (G)\otimes_{\max}C^* (G)
> $$

Thanks in advance,

Valerio

Comment: @Valerio: in order to avoid clogging up the comments to Scott L's answer, it may be best if you email me some time next week (regarding VN(G) being injective when G is connected) and I will try to dig through my collection of PDFs. I have Palmer volume 2 open in front of me and I cannot find the reference which pm has suggested in the comments below.

Answer (score 7):

In Lance's 1972 paper "On Nuclear $C^\ast$-algebras," it is mentioned that there are non-amenable groups for which $C^\ast(G)$ is nuclear. The main goal of the paper is to prove that when $G$ is *discrete*, then $C^\ast(G)$ is nuclear if and only if $G$ is amenable, but he does mention very briefly that in the general case, $C^\ast(G)$ can be nuclear even for a non-amenable group. In particular, he mentions $\rm{SL}(2, \mathbb{C})$ as a specific example.

Comment: Perfect, I think that $SL(2,\mathbb C)$ answers the original question. The question looks apparently harder for countable discrete groups. Indeed, *Kirchberg's property* is quite weaker than nuclearity. 

Comment: You could take G to be any connected group - this follows from Connes's observation that VN of such a group is injective, although when G is Lie the result is really implicitly due to Dixmier/Pukanszky, and when G is semi simple Lie, its $C^\ast$-algebra is Type I by results of Harish-Chandra/Godement. The fact that SL(2,C) is Type I probably goes back to Bargmann or Gelfand, I forget. If self-advertising is not too gauche, see the remarks here http://ifwisdomwereteachable.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/primary-literature-whats-that-gramps/

Comment: Thank you very much, Yemon, for this interesting comment. So, the question is really interesting for countable groups..

Comment: By the way, I would be interested to see the proof that the von Neumann algebra of a connected group is injective. Could you please give a reference?

Comment: There is a slight misstatement in what I wrote - VN of a connected group is injective, but I'm not sure this will make the full C-star algebra nuclear. However this last claim is true for G semisimple Lie, as I said above.

Comment: OK, I am anyway interested to see the proof that VN of a connected group is injective. Could you please provide a reference or a sketch (in case it is easy)?

Comment: Dear Valerio, look at Banach Algebras and the General Theory of *-Algebras, Band 2 von Theodore W. Palmer and search for nuclearity.

Comment: Dear pm: **really?** Dear Valerio, Palmer's book will not help you understand the proof. I am willing to bet a small amount that for the case of general connected Lie groups it will refer you to Connes's paper, but not mention that Connes's paper will also not help you understand the proof, for which you really have to see the original paper of Dixmier (with a slight technical gap apparently filled by Pukanszky)

Comment: The paper of Dixmier can be found at http://www.numdam.org/item?id=ASENS_1969_4_2_3_423_0 - I am not sure if the gap in one place, corrected by Pukanszky in http://www.numdam.org/item?id=ASENS_1971_4_4_4_457_0 , affects the proof of that particular result. The key point is that a connected group G has a closed, unimodular Type I subgroup H such that G/H is abelian (see the proof of lemme 5.2 in Dixmier's paper); so VN(H) is injective for relatively easy reasons, and then one needs a crossed-product argument to deduce injectivity of VN(G). 

Comment: (With apologies to Scott L for clogging up "his" comments)

Comment: Dear Yemon Choi, I have just read a small passage in this book, and it seems to deal with similar questions. It was just a suggestion for some reading. Sorry, if this didn't not help the MO.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know any example (with discrete $G$), but I can at least say that if such example is known to exist, it is nontrivial. Indeed, it was a long-standing open problem to find a nonnuclear $C^*$ algebra $A$ such that $A\otimes A^{op}$ carries only one $C^*$-norm. It is (one of) the main result(s) of the paper by Kirchberg that you cite that such a $C^*$-algebra exists (but the example is not a group $C^*$-algebra). My reference for this is Pisier's Introduction to operator space theory, Chapter 22.

Since $C^*(G)$ is always isomorphic to $C^*(G)^{op}$, you are asking whether $A$ can be taken as the full $C^*$-algebra of a discrete group. This refined question is not answered by Kirchberg, and a rapid bibliographic search did not give anything.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mikael, for this interesting comment.

Answer (score 0):

Wiersma solved that problem finding many groups with inequality.

Comment: Could you give a reference?

Comment: @StefanKohl My guess is that he is referring to the following paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2654